# Allow a post loaded app to get privilege permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source, whitelist

I am developing on aosp. I have a post-loaded app with a package name com.test.packagetest. Is there a way for this app to get privilege permission (without using the signature) like for example putting the package name on a whitelist somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:  https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist "?